# ASP.MVC RedirectAction: Preserve Original Referrer When Redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, referrer

I have a page I use to log visits then redirect to specific page.

I'd like to set the referrer of the redirect to the original referrer to the request to my analytics page.

I'm using a RedirectAction to make the redirect.

```
    public RedirectResult  Index()
    {
        var it = new IncomingTraffic();
        using (var db = new WebEntity())
        {
            it.created = DateTime.Now;
            it.referrer = Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "" : Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString;
            it.userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
            it.ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            it.redirectUrl = GetRedirect();
            db.IncomingTraffics.Add(it);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        //I'd like to change the referrer to it.referrer for the redirect
        return Redirect(it.redirectUrl);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Browser you're using?

Comment: This isn't browser specific and should work with any browser's incoming request. The browsers I have installed on my machine are Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Comment: @Proximo I also have this problem... would you mind sharing how you solved it?